# given digits $2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4$, find the number of distinct $4$-digit numbers

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have been given digits $2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4$, and I would like to get distinct $4$-digits numbers. So how could I retrieve that?

$$\frac{9!}{2!3!4!} = 1260$$

but its a wrong answer. Correct answer is $72$.

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: How did you get $9!/(2!*3!*4!)$? Show your working.

Answer (score 2):

There are $3^4=81$ numbers containing four  digits from $\{2,3,4\}$ without any restrictions. Some of these numbers are forbidden: $2222$, $3333$, and numbers containing three $2$s and a $3$ or a $4$. There are eight of the latter, since there are four slots for the $3$, resp., the $4$. It follows that we have $81-2-8=71$ admissible numbers.

Comment: $2222$ and $3333$ wouldn't be possible since you have only have two $2$s and three $3$s. $4444$ is possible so the answer would be $71+1=72$ I believe (which is what OP posted as the answer)

Comment: @Brenton This answer takes into account the fact that $4444$ is not used.  This answer is correct; the answer key is wrong.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You'right, I misread.